# Creating a WPF Ellipse Object with Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to create a WPF ellipse object using Powershell... I loaded the assembly... but, no luck creating an Ellipse Object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.ellipse?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

```
## Coverting to c# into Powershell
#   var ellipse 
#     = new Ellipse() { Width = 1.5, 
#       Height = 1.5, 
#       Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) };

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$x = New-Object -TypeName [System.Windows.Shapes.Shape]::Ellipse

ERROR: New-Object : Cannot find type [[System.Windows.Shapes.Shape]::Ellipse]: verify that the assembly containing
this type is loaded.
```

Here's a more specific example of what i want to do:

```
#Build the GUI
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    Width = "800" Height = "600" ShowInTaskbar = "True">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas"></Canvas>
</Window>
"@

$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$canvas = $window.FindName("Canvas")
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
```

```
function add_point{
    param(
        $canvas,
        $x,
        $y,
        $rbg
    )
    
    # How to rewrite the following 
    # c# code as Powershell????
    var ellipse = new Ellipse() { 
      Width = 1.5, 
      Height = 1.5, 
      Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) 
    };
    # static function in WPF Canvas Class?
    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, point.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, point.Y);

    # Call Childer.Add member of $canvas
    m_canvas.Children.Add(ellipse); 
    # Probably, in powershell:
    # $canvas.Children.Add(ellipse)
}

add_point $canvas 1 1 0xFF0000
add_point $canvas 1 2 0xFF0000
add_point $canvas 1 3 0xFF0000
add_point $canvas 2 1 0xFF0000

$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Build the GUI
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    Width = "800" Height = "600" ShowInTaskbar = "True">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas"></Canvas>
</Window>
"@
 
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$canvas = $window.FindName("Canvas")

function add_point{
    param(
        [System.Windows.Controls.Canvas]$canvas,
        $x,
        $y,
        $r,
        $g,
        $b
    )
    $color = [System.Windows.Media.Color]::FromRgb($r, $g, $b)
    $brush = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush
    $brush.Color = $color
    
    #var ellipse = new Ellipse() { Width = 1.5, Height = 1.5, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) };
    $ellipse = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse
    $ellipse.Width   = 1.5
    $ellipse.Height  = 1.5  
    $ellipse.Stroke  = $brush
    
    [System.Windows.Controls.Canvas]::SetLeft($ellipse, $x)
    [System.Windows.Controls.Canvas]::SetTop($ellipse,  $y)
    
    $canvas.Children.Add($ellipse) | out-null
}

for ($i=0; $i -lt 100; $i++) {
    add_point $canvas $i $i  0xFF  0x00  0x00
}

$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```